# Html table alignment issue in IE 11 and IE 8

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I have created one HTML table with fixed header and scrollable body. But when I resize the browser window or zoom in or zoom out the browser the table alignment changes. I want to view the complete table even if browser window is resized or zoomed in or zoomed out.

And I need it to work in IE 11 and IE 8

I have tried many solutions from google, but I couldn't make it work.

Kindly help, I need the solution for this issue badly.

Here is the fiddle:
[Scrollable Table](https://jsfiddle.net/bijay_ps/g68vf7m1/3/)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div td{
text-align: center;
}
</style>
 <script language="Javascript">
 window.onload = init;
 window.onresize = init;

 function init() {
 var eTable = document.getElementById("headers");
  if (eTable != null){

 eTable.style.width = document.getElementById('data').offsetWidth;
 document.getElementById('th1').style.width = document.getElementById('td1').offsetWidth;
 document.getElementById('th2').style.width = document.getElementById('td2').offsetWidth;
 document.getElementById('th3').style.width = document.getElementById('td3').offsetWidth;
 document.getElementById('th4').style.width = document.getElementById('td4').offsetWidth;
 document.getElementById('th5').style.width = document.getElementById('td5').offsetWidth;
 document.getElementById('th6').style.width = document.getElementById('td6').offsetWidth;
 document.getElementById('th7').style.width = document.getElementById('td7').offsetWidth;
 document.getElementById('th8').style.width = document.getElementById('td8').offsetWidth;
  document.getElementById('th9').style.width =  document.getElementById('td9').offsetWidth;
 } }
```

```
</head>
   <body>   
    <table id="headers" width="100%">
            <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="blue">
            <th align="center" id="th1">Head 1<br></th>                      
            <th align="center" id="th2">Head 2<br>
        </th>
        <th align="center" id="th3">
            Head 3<br>
        </th>
        <th align="center" id="th4">
            Head 4<br>
        </th>           
        <th align="center" id="th5">
            Head 5<br>
        </th>           
        <th align="center" id="th6">
            Head 6<br>
        </th>           
        <th align="center" id="th7">
            Head 7<br>
        </th>           
        <th align="center" id="th8">
            Head 8<br>
        </th>
        <th align="center" id="th9">
            Head 9<br>
        </th>
        </tr></thead>
</table>
        <div style="height: 275px; overflow-y: auto;">

        <table id="data" width="100%">


                <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>
                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>
                    </tr>   
                <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>
                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>
                    </tr>   <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>
                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>
                    </tr>   <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>
                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>
                    </tr>   <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>
                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>
                    </tr>   <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>
                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>
                    </tr>   <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>
                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>
                    </tr>   <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>
                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>
                    </tr>   <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>
                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>
                    </tr>   <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>
                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>
                    </tr>   <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>
                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>
                    </tr>   <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>
                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>
                    </tr>   <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>
                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>
                    </tr>   <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>
                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>
                    </tr>   <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>
                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>
                    </tr>   <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>
                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>
                    </tr>   <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>
                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>
                    </tr>   <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>
                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>
                    </tr>   

            </table>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure IE8 doesn't support anything of the sort, but you can set @media sizes for IE11 to do what you are looking for.

Comment: I haven't tried @media, but I have updated the code and have changed the fiddle also... can anyone please check once again

Comment: ok, if you dont have an answer by this afternoon. I will do it when I am off work for ya. Adding the fiddle helps a ton!

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of google searches and going through many solutions mentioned in stackoverflow, I finally got the solution to this problem, so I am sharing it here, here is the code, which is working for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#table-wrapper {
position:absolute;
left: 30px;
top: 50px;
}
#table-scroll {
height:250px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

#table-scroll table {
height: 250px;
}
#table-wrapper table {
width: 1300px;
display: block; 
}

#table-wrapper table thead th .text {
position:absolute;   
top:-20px;
z-index:2;
height:20px;
border:1px solid red;
}

#table-wrapper table thead th{
background-color: orange;
height: 25px;
}

#table-wrapper table tbody td{
background-color: grey;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>  
<div id="table-wrapper">


<table id="headers">
        <thead><tr>
            <th align="center" id="th1" width = "9%;">
            Head 1<br>
        </th>                        
        <th align="center" id="th2" width = "28%;">
            Head 2<br>
        </th>
        <th align="center" id="th3" width = "9%;">
            Head is longer<br>
        </th>
        <th  id="th4" width = "9%;">
            Head is even more lengthy than others<br>
        </th>       

        </th>   
        <th align="center" id="th5" width = "13%;" >
            Head 5<br>
        </th>                                   
        <th align="center" id="th6" width = "8%;">
            Head 6<br>
        </th>           
        <th align="center" id="th7" width = "8%;">
            Head 7<br>
        </th>           
        <th align="center" id="th8" width = "8%;">
            Head 8<br>
        </th>
        <th align="center" id="th9" width = "8%;">
            Head 9<br>
        </th>
        </tr></thead>
</table>

        <div id="table-scroll">

        <table id="data">

            <tbody>

                <tr >
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>

                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>

                    </tr><tr >
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>

                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>

                    </tr><tr >
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>

                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>

                    </tr><tr >
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>

                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>

                    </tr><tr >
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>

                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>

                    </tr><tr >
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>

                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>

                    </tr><tr >
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>

                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>

                    </tr><tr >
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>

                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>

                    </tr><tr >
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>

                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>

                    </tr><tr >
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>

                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>

                    </tr><tr >
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>

                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>

                    </tr><tr >
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>

                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>

                    </tr><tr >
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>

                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>

                    </tr><tr >
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>

                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>

                    </tr><tr >
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>

                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>

                    </tr><tr >
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>

                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>

                    </tr><tr >
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>

                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>

                    </tr><tr >
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>

                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>

                    </tr><tr >
                    <td id="td1" width="9%">column 1

                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" width="28%">
                        COlumn 2
                    </td>
                    <td id="td3" width="9%">
                        Column 3
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" width="9%">
                        Column 4
                    </td>

                    <td id="td5" width="13%">
                    Column 5
                    </td>
                <td id="td6" width="8%">
                    Column 6
                    </td>
                <td id="td7" width="8%">
                    Column 7
                    </td>
                <td id="td8" width="8%">
                    Column 8
                    </td>
                <td id="td9" width="8%">
                    Column 9
                    </td>

                    </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```